# Slack freezes on incoming message

Tags: debian, kde, slack

I have to kill the PID or wait a long time before I can use it again. The following comes up on `webapp-console.log` as soon as Slack freezes:

> error: [DESKTOP] 'desktop.notice.shouldPlaySound' is missing or not a
>   function

I'm running Debian GNU/Linux bullseye/sid, with KDE desktop.

Comment: Does executing `notify-send foobar` in the terminal work?

Answer (score 1):

I also struggled with this for a while but solved it by running `dunst` at startup in my desktop session. This is on Debian 10 (Buster) with Mate Desktop.

This appears to [apply to a lot of Electron apps](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7831), not just Slack.